# Isometric isomorphisms preserve density.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

In which result could I find this result? I just tried it but I would like to have it as a reference. Thank you.

Let $X, Y$ Banach spaces and $f:X\to Y$ isometric isomorphism. If $D$ is dense in $X$ then $F(D)$ is dense in $Y$.

My proof. For each $y\in Y$, exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Because $x\in X$, exists $\left\{x_n\right\}_n\subset D$ such that $\lim_n x_n=x$ in $X$. Then $\lim_n \left\|f(x_n)-y\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|f(x_n)-f(x)\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|f(x_n-x)\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|x_n-x\right\|_{X}=0$.

Comment: This is fine. Where is your doubt?

Comment: It is not a doubt. Is where I could find a book where this result appears (as a theorem, or lemma etc)? or is it just an exercise?

Comment: It is too trivial to be stated as a theorem in any book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $y\in Y$, exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Because $x\in X$, exists $\left\{x_n\right\}_n\subset D$ such that $\lim_n x_n=x$ in $X$. Then $\lim_n \left\|f(x_n)-y\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|f(x_n)-f(x)\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|f(x_n-x)\right\|_{Y}=\lim_n \left\|x_n-x\right\|_{X}=0$.